# PostgreSQL group by and order by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a date column. I wanted to get the count of months and display them in the order of months. Months should be displayed as 'Jan', 'Feb' etc. If I use to_char function, the order by happens on text. I can use extract(month from dt), but that will also display month in number format. This is part of a report and month should be displayed in 'Mon' format only.

```
SELECT to_char(dt,'Mon'), COUNT(*)  FROM tb GROUP BY to_char(dt,'Mon') ORDER BY to_char(dt,'Mon');
 to_char | count 
---------+-------
 Dec     |     1
 Jan     |     1
 Jul     |     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select month, total
from (
    select
        extract(month from dt) as month_number,
        to_char(dt,'mon') as month,
        count(*) as total
    from tb
    group by 1, 2
) s
order by month_number
```

Comment: I am trying not to have the month in numeric format in my report. Is that possible? Edited my question to add this.

Comment: @Jayadevan Can't  you just use the desired columns by alias? I gave alias to the columns in the edited answer.

Comment: I am using this in a perl script and dumping the output into an excel. Right now the perl array is being dumped as it is into excel. If I have extra columns, I will have to pick and choose elements. That was why I am trying to get only those columns I needed. May be writing an outer query to pick only those columns might work. Theoretically, the order by need not likely to hold if I write an outer query, isn't it, though for all practical purposes, it will be ordered.

Comment: It would be good if you could explain why and how this query answers the question. Code-only answers tend to be harder for other users to apply to their own situation in future.